Removing a child node in xslt
[XSLT 1.0]
I have an xml doc like this :
<doc>
 <article>
  <photo>
   <caption>
    <p>
     caption text here with <i>italic</i> here and <b>bold</b> here<credit>photo 
     copyright</credit>
    </p>
   </caption>
  </photo>
 </article>
</doc>

So the <credit> tag is nested in the <p> tag.
I have templates to copy the <i> and <b> tags, like this :
<xsl:template match="i">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

What I need to get in the output is : the caption text with <i> and <b> tags, and then the photo copyright. I also need to have a line-break between both (I mean between caption text and photo copyright) ; and I don't want to repeat the photo copyright (I don't want to have it 2 times, in both lines in the output).
So requested output is :
caption text here with `<i>`italic`</i>` here and `<b>`bold`</b>` here
photo copyright

I can do this :
<xsl:apply-templates select="caption/p/text()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="caption/p/credit"/>

… but here I'm loosing my <i> and <b> tags, which I do need in my output… And I have no line-break.
I can also do this :
<xsl:apply-templates select="caption/p"/>
<xsl:value-of select="caption/p/credit"/>

… but here I have the photo copyright 2 times. And I have no line break either…
So I was looking for some trick to : 1/ keep my <i> and <b> tags - 2/ get a line break between caption text and photo copyright - 3/ get rid of the <credit> node in my caption text output.
And I did find a way. In my xsl now I just have :
<xsl:apply-templates select="caption/p"/>
<xsl:value-of select="caption/p/credit"/>

Just like above… but I added a template like this :
<xsl:template match="credit">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

And… I must say, this is working, in a way, as I do keep my <i> and <b> tags, I do get a line break between caption text and photo copyright, and I do get rid of the <credit> node in my caption text output. Problem is : I feel this is quite awkward…
So please how would you do this in a better way ? I'm new to xsl and I have no idea…
[EDIT]
Full xsl I have at this stage is :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/doc">
<doc>
    <article>
            <xsl:for-each select="article/photo">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="caption/p"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="caption/p/credit"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </article>
</doc>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="credit">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="i">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="i[../../b]|b[../../i]">
    <xsl:element name="emstrong">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Please edit your question and add the exact expected output. Seeing the full XSLT you have now would also be helpful.

@michael.hor257k I edited my question with full xsl code, and expected output, maybe it's more clear now.

Try this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="credit">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <!-- 
      If you want to get rit of the line-break inside credit, i.e. do a normalize-space like this
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/>
    -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>



So I was looking for some trick to : 1/ keep my <i> and <b> tags - 2/ get a line break between caption text and photo copyright - 3/ get rid of the <credit> node in my caption text output.

To do all of that you only need the identity transform template and another template that does:
<xsl:template match="credit">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

But it seems you also want to remove the photo, caption and p wrappers, so you would also need:
<xsl:template match="photo | caption | p">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

with the instruction:
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

added at the top level of the stylesheet.
